# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3, drools, kie

I am trying to execute kie-workbench rules from java application,succeeded with drools-6.1.0.Final version,when i upgraded to drools-6.2.0 i getting the following exception:(Maven version-3.2.3)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/aether/resolution/ArtifactResolutionException
    at org.kie.scanner.ArtifactResolver.<init>(ArtifactResolver.java:36)
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.getArtifactResolver(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:85)
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.loadArtifact(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:95)
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.loadArtifact(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:91)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.loadKieModuleFromMavenRepo(KieRepositoryImpl.java:113)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.getKieModule(KieRepositoryImpl.java:99)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.getKieModule(KieRepositoryImpl.java:76)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:95)
    at com.datu.RuleIdRunner.main(RuleIdRunner.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 9 more
```

here is my pom.xml file:

{
4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.datu.rule</groupId>
<artifactId>Batchsample-Rule</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Batchsample-Rule</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-aether-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.drools</groupId> <artifactId>named-kiesession</artifactId> 
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-persistence-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>knowledge-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

}

Any help.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Update your maven from your current version to a higher version.

Tips from https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM-133?_sscc=t